# How to remove the group column values from the pig bag?

Tags: mapreduce, bigdata, apache-pig

I have the below output from a pig script.

```
{(001,Kumar,Jayasuriya,1123456754,Matara),  (001,Kumar,Sangakkara,112722892,Kandy),(001,Rajiv,Reddy,9848022337,Hyderabad)}
{(002,siddarth,Battacharya,9848022338,Kolkata)}
{(003,Rajesh,Khanna,9848022339,Delhi)}
{(004,Preethi,Agarwal,9848022330,Pune)}
{(005,Trupthi,Mohanthy,9848022336,Bhuwaneshwar)}
{(006,Archana,Mishra,9848022335,Chennai)}
{(007,Kumar,Dharmasena,758922419,Colombo)}
{(008,Mahela,Jayawerdana,765557103,Colombo)}
```

Below is the script I used to generate this.

```
students = LOAD 'student_data10.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (id:chararray,fname:chararray,lname:chararray,tp:chararray,city:chararray);
group_students = GROUP students by (id);
group_students2  = FOREACH group_students GENERATE $1;
```

I need the Ids out from the pig bag. That is "001","002"..."007" shouldn't be there in the output. Below is an example of the output I need.

```
{(Kumar,Jayasuriya,1123456754,Matara),  (Kumar,Sangakkara,112722892,Kandy),(Rajiv,Reddy,9848022337,Hyderabad)}
{(siddarth,Battacharya,9848022338,Kolkata)}
```

I know I could achieve this by saying table.columnName for all the columns that I need in the output bag. But I need to get this output without mentioning the column names. How can I achieve this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you copied the output as it is ? the first line is not grouped by id and fname !

Comment: sorry its grouped by id! I edited the question